# Hibernate many to many, with extra columns select using extra column in where

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

so I have followed this page and it is now working for findAll
https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

but what I can find nowhere to tell me is how to use the extra column in the where section of a select, in My DAO.

so taking the stock example in that page I only want to select stock that was stocked in the last week.

findByDate (for example)

here are the tables from the example:

```
CREATE TABLE `stock` (
  `STOCK_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `STOCK_CODE` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `STOCK_NAME` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`STOCK_ID`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `UNI_STOCK_NAME` (`STOCK_NAME`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNI_STOCK_ID` (`STOCK_CODE`) USING BTREE
)

CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `CATEGORY_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `DESC` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CATEGORY_ID`) USING BTREE
)

CREATE TABLE  `stock_category` (
  `STOCK_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `CATEGORY_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_DATE` DATE NOT NULL,
  `CREATED_BY` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`STOCK_ID`,`CATEGORY_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CATEGORY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`CATEGORY_ID`) 
             REFERENCES `category` (`CATEGORY_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_STOCK_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`STOCK_ID`) 
             REFERENCES `stock` (`STOCK_ID`)
)
```

I have found pages to help me get so far but every tutorial appears to be missing this vital fact. Could somebody help point me further.

if I knew hibernate well the answer may be obvious but I don't

Comment: What *extra column* in which *where*? You mean the one that I don't see here?

Comment: *I need to do this in my software at work.* I can do that for you as additional work if you wish for split of your payout if you wish.

Comment: @Antoniossss, the title is just a summary, the extra detail is in the text body: 'so taking the stock example in that page I only want to select stock that was stocked in the last week.'  I am only asking for documentation, a link to helpful articles. This isn't actually the code i am writing, just the example provided, so any answers to this problem won't be used in production code. I was just answering "this isn't coding"